# Localize iPad app at run time

Tags: ipad, ios4, localization, nib

I'm developing an app that require a localization at run time, i mean that it will be a button to change the language instantly, i've searched about localization and what i've found is how to localize the app depend on the iPhone international language.

I've localize all the nib files i have and redesign each nib file according to it's language, but how i can change the nib file when the user click on the button ?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351445/runtime-change-the-language-localization-in-three20

Comment: I've read this post before, but the solution for the three20 library, i'm developing an iPad app that don't use any external library. thx for commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly you can use a project created by someone: [Advance Localization in iOS apps](https://github.com/object2dot0/Advance-Localization-in-ios-apps)

Or there is another method, to implement it by yourself.You must have all localization files in your project:

```
@implementation Language

static NSBundle *bundle = nil;

+(void)initialize {
 NSArray* languages = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
 NSString *current = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
 [self setLanguage:current];

}

/*
  example calls:
  [Language setLanguage:@"it"];
  [Language setLanguage:@"de"];
*/
+(void)setLanguage:(NSString *)l {
 NSLog(@"preferredLang: %@", l);
 NSString *path = [[ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:l ofType:@"lproj" ];
 bundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];
}

+(NSString *)get:(NSString *)key alter:(NSString *)alternate {
 return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:alternate table:nil];
}

@end
```

This code is good for what you need. But this is only the base. So each text must be loaded with the `get:alter:` method, so it will be loaded in the correct language. As you see at initialization this class will use the system language, but after you call the `setLanguage` method, then it will use the language you've setup. After you set a language with the `get:alter:` method, you should reload all your text in your view controller, by calling the `get:alter:` method again for each text that appears and set the result to the desired label or textfield or to any other `NSString` type parameter that needs i18n. So there is more work, but this is a very good base. I don't think it can happen automatically, you have to code.

Comment: Great solution, but this work when i have a start up page that ask the user which language you prefer to use, So, the main question is how can i reload the current view controller that appear on the screen and the controller that already loaded in the memory.
Note: I'm using a TabBar project template which is load all the tap when the user click on them and unload them if there is a memory warning. Again, Great answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [Creating a localized iPhone app but allowing the user to change language for the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245975/creating-a-localized-iphone-app-but-allowing-the-user-to-change-language-for-the).

Basically, you split up your localizations into tables and bundles rather than using the built-in localization system. You look your strings up from per-language tables and your nib files from per-langage bundles.

Comment: Great answer, can you supply the answer with some source code, a sample project will be great. Thank you in advance.